# Is there a way to speed up basic math in python for non-array and non-matrix multiplication, division, and addition?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, math

I always read that if I had structured my code for matrix math or large array math that Numpy would speed it up over default Python math.  But for the sake of a thought experiment, if you really had to do thousands of floating point multiplications, divisions, and arithmetic in Python but could not use a matrix for some reason...  Is there any library or syntax that could speed anything like this up at all?  Sounds like just using numpy here would not be a significant gain because it is not matrix math.  Is that correct?

I should also add that I am looking for something that is a simple solution to install.  Some of the libraries that pre-compile Python create excess complexity.  But open to all answers and opinions.

Comment: Have you looked at numba? https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: I suspect you'll need to be more specific.  `numpy` gains its speed by performing many calculations in compiled code - with just one python expression.  The compact layout of the array data helps.  If instead all your numbers of in lists, or one number per python variable, the interpreted object access takes up more time than the calculations themselves.  `timeit` for a simple expression like `1000.243/0.34 + 34*2` is in the `ns`.

Comment: `numexpr` describes itself as `Fast numerical array expression evaluator for Python, NumPy, PyTables, pandas, bcolz and more`

Comment: Are things like Numba all about vector or matrix math for performance gain?  Is there anything that would multiply say 8.6*8.3 repetitively 20,000 times faster than default python would? In other words just very simple arithmetic much faster?

Comment: @hpaulj *"timeit for a simple expression like 1000.243/0.34 + 34*2 is in the ns"* - Careful, that might mislead readers who don't know that Python does the computation already during compilation, so that timeit only measures loading (and dropping) the resulting constant.

Comment: Something that you should note is that while numba speeds up code significantly, there are still limits due to the memory model, cache, the ffi and compilation, using it can get you within an order of magnitude of well written C++, but it's not a replacement for well written C++ libraries for performance, you can't just slap it on your project and expect the same performance as if you have written it in C++, so if you want the best performance you should write stuff in a low level language like C++ directly, numba is good for a large python app with a few functions that need to be faster.

Comment: One of the easiest ways is probably to switch the version of python you're using. If you're on CPython and you'd doing a lot of CPU-bound work, you probably want to switch to PyPy, which is much better at that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments - numba can provide some good speed ups ... depending on the specific use case. For example:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np


@jit(nopython=True)
def multiply_stuff_numba(n):
    tmp = 0
    for i in range(n):
        tmp += 8.6 * i
    return tmp

def multiply_stuff_python(n):
    tmp = 0
    for i in range(n):
        tmp += 8.6 * i
    return tmp
```

When comparing speed:

```
%timeit multiply_stuff_python(10_000_000)
```

output:

```
555 ms ± 617 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and

```
%timeit multiply_stuff_numba(10_000_000)
```

output:

```
8.68 ms ± 42.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @KellyBundy in the comments, `%timeit` can be misleading if the function is not actually doing any compute. For example, using a poorly thought out example from an earlier version of this post, numba seems to figure out no compute is required if the return value is removed resulting in an unrealistically fast estimate.

eg.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def multiply_stuff_numba_2(n):
    tmp = 0
    for i in range(n):
        tmp += 8.6 * i
    return
%timeit multiply_stuff_numba_2(100_000_000)
```

output:

```
165 ns ± 2.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

(Can confirm no compute is hapenning since changing the argument does not change time at all)

The main point of this post is that numba is one solution (among many) which can speed up simple arithmetic when compared to pure python implementation, which I think is the crux of the OPs question.

**EDIT 2**

As pointed out by @user19077881, the speed up seen in first example is actually due to numba optimising the loop, not the math operation itself. So if the OPs question was specifically about a single native math operator, then no, numba does not provide speed up. However, given the OPs comment - *if you really had to do thousands of floating point multiplications* - the above answer is probably still relevant.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I have edited my answer so function should actually do something now

Comment: Certainly better :-). I think with the original code, numba was cheating somehow, but now with the random function call, it seems to not optimize that away. Although now I think the random function call is relatively expensive, masking the speed difference. And I think the Python version is extra punished by working with numpy, which doesn't reflect pure Python speed.

Comment: Yeah another good point. I have edited one more time ... :) . The main point of my post was that numba is one solution which can speed up pure python in many cases, and in particular is not just for array based compute which the OP mentioned in a comment above. The example could have been better ..

Comment: Looks good to me now.

Comment: The in-built math functions in Python are a wrapper around the C functions and  optimized.  This seems to be what the OP was originally questioning. Numba (and numpy etc) speed up the access and loading of a sequences of values used in a math operation (using loops or arrays) but don't speed the math calculation itself.

Comment: @user19077881 Does that mean numba still operates on numbers as Python objects, not as something more efficient like C ints/floats?